# Sprintf in Grails

Tags: grails, printf

I got problem in grails, when i want to create some Code for Transfer Transaction.

```
def beforeInsert(){
    Integer count= Transfer.count()+1
    Integer width= transactionMaster.width

    String c = sprintf('%05d',count)

    number = transactionMaster.code+"/"+c
}
```

the code above especially in variable number, will give result like this : 00007.

Now the problem is, how to make '%05'  change according to variable width??

For example if the width is 5, then the number will give result: 00007
if the width is 2, then the number will give result: 07
if the width is 10, then the number will give result: 0000000007

hope someone can help and if you have any solutions, can you mail me to : medmodest@gmail.com

i rarely open this website, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a groovy question, you can use groovy GString.

Instead of:

```
...
String c = sprintf('%05d',count)
...
```

Use this:

```
...
String c = sprintf("%0${width}d",count)
...
```

Hope this helps